# localStorage not clearing when using setInterval() for JS timer

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am working on a personal project and I am making use of JS to implement a simple countdown timer. There are several requirements that need to be addressed:
- The timer starts when the page is loaded
- When the user wishes to leave the page, they are warned that their progress will be lost, hence, the timer is reset.

I am making use of localStorage to keep the remaining time, since every time the user submits a form that is on the page, the page is reloaded (I understand that it is better to use AJAX, but for the time being, I am trying to make it work properly as it is). You can see my code below:

```
var submit_form;
var timeLeft;

function startTimer(duration, content) {
    var timer = duration, min, sec;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (--timer < 0) {
            //redirect here;
            submit_form = true;
            localStorage.removeItem("remainingTime");
            window.location.replace("some url");
        } else {
            min = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            sec = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            min = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;
            sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;

            localStorage.setItem("remainingTime", timer);
            console.log(timer);

            content.textContent = min + ":" + sec;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    submit_form = false;
    console.log(submit_form);

    if (localStorage.getItem("remainingTime")) {
        timeLeft = localStorage.getItem("remainingTime");
    } else {
        timeLeft = 60;
    }
    var display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(timeLeft, display);
};

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (submit_form != true) {
        localStorage.removeItem("remainingTime");
        window.localStorage.clear();
        return "You will lose all your progress!/nAre you sure you want to quit?";
    }
};
```

'submit_form' is used for controlling when 'onbeforeunload' gets triggered - When the user submits the form, it shouldn't trigger.

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" id="search-button" onclick="submit_form = true;">Submit</button>
```

The issue that I am facing, which is killing me, is that *sometimes* when the user tries to leave the page, i.e. 'onbeforeunload' is triggered, the localStorage doesn't always clear. Therefore, when they come back to the page, the timer doesn't start from the beginning, but instead, from where they left off.

I have tried a few variations of the code above, and my best guess is that setInterval() might be the reason for localStorage not clearing every time.

Comment: First deleting the "progress" and then giving the warning is the wrong order...

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: You're removing everything from `localStorage` (`window.localStorage.clear()`) and only then ask the user if he really want's this (_"Are you sure...?").

Comment: When 'onbeforeunload' is triggered, the user gets an option either to leave or stay, during which the timer is "frozen". If they decide to stay, the timer continues as normal. The localStorage stills clears at that point, but 'startTimer' functions takes whatever is on the display as an argument